# Dynamically generate multiple canvas area based on json provided

Tags: angular, html5-canvas

I am using angular2 and html5 canvas. Based on json provided I want to create multiple divs with canvas area inside them.

This is how generate my divs with canvas area (HTML CODE)

```
<div class="masterpage" *ngFor="let x of masterPages" draggable [dragScope]="'masterpage'" [dragData]="x">
    <canvas #myCanvas width="105" height="149" style="background:lightgray;"></canvas>
</div>
```

.ts code

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let canvas = this.myCanvas.nativeElement;
    this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.tick(this.masterPages);
}

tick(masterPages) {
    var ctx = this.context;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
    for (let j = 0; j < this.masterPages[this.count].areas.length; j++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.masterPages[this.count].areas[j].type;
        ctx.fillRect(masterPages[this.count].areas[j].x / 2, masterPages[this.count].areas[j].y / 2, masterPages[this.count].areas[j].width / 2, masterPages[this.count].areas[j].height / 2);
    }
    this.count = this.count + 1;
}
```

below is my json

```
masterPages = [{
        areas: [
            {
                type: "FlowArea",
                width: "183.0",
                x: "12.0",
                y: "40.0",
                id: "FAR.1",
                height: "237.0"
            },
            {
                type: "StaticArea",
                width: "210.0",
                x: "0.0",
                y: "7.0",
                id: "SAR.2",
                height: "25.0"
            },
            {
                type: "StaticArea",
                width: "210.0",
                x: "0.0",
                y: "282.0",
                id: "SAR.1",
                height: "15.0"
            },
            {
                type: "StaticArea",
                width: "2.0",
                x: "6.0",
                y: "26.0",
                id: "SAR.3",
                height: "256.0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        areas: [
            {
                type: "FlowArea",
                width: "183.0",
                x: "12.0",
                y: "13.25",
                id: "FAR.1",
                height: "265.0"
            },
            {
                type: "StaticArea",
                width: "210.0",
                x: "0.0",
                y: "282.0",
                id: "SAR.1",
                height: "15.0"
            }
        ]
    }
    ];
```

according to json both canvas should have some shapes but in my case second canvas is coming empty

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using @ViewChildren instead of @ViewChild and iterate over each canvas using

```
let canvas = this.myCanvas.toArray()[i].nativeElement;
```

So who will get access to each of the canvas area created dynamically.

Comment: Thanks.. Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the identifier (#myCanvas) can handle only one
reference to an element.

And unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, there's no way to generate multiple
unique identifiers dinamically.

In order to update several different canvas elements, you will need to get their
references by some other means. One of them is to manipulate the DOM directly,
but it's not recommended, like:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas' + i);
```

Another example would be to use a querySelector (via ElementRef):

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.myCanvasClass');
```

Take a look and the ViewChildren documentation. It might shed some light to what
you're trying to do:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-decorator.html

Comment: Any other method where in I can create multiple canvas dynamically?

Comment: You've succedeed in creating multiple canvas elements. Now you should focus on how to get a reference to them. If I were you I'd also try to create a component just to encapsulate the canvas and manipulate it using this.elementRef.nativeElement and parameters passed to the component as @Input()

Answer (score 0):

Just get the json from server and parse it with JSON.parse.

For drawing a canvas chart.

You can used this library javaScript plotting for jQuery - http://www.flotcharts.org/

It's will help you plot a graph via JSON data.

For ajax update - http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/index.html
For realtime update - http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html
Sample static plot - http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/basic-usage/index.htm

```
 var d = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
    d .push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
}
var do = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];
// A null signifies separate line segments

var dd = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

$.plot("#placeholder", [ d, do, dd]);
```